# This function syntax is confusing me

Tags: opengl, c++

gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)

I have never seen this syntax before. Presumably glfGetProcAddres is a function, but it has the brackets behind it. Is this only possible in open gl or is my c++ trash.

Comment: "*it has the brackets behind it*" Do you mean in front of it?

Comment: You are right. I have it reversed for some reason. Can youbtell me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a fundamental question about the C++ programming language entirely unrelated to the problem of computer graphics.

Comment: I will delete it sorry. I didn't mean to piss anybody off, im just a newbie, the negative votes are a bit harsh :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of `glfwGetProcAddress` is:

```
GLFWglproc glfwGetProcAddress(const char *);
```

It's a function that takes a string and returns a `GLFWglproc`. which is defined as

```
typedef void(* GLFWglproc) (void);
```

Essentially, that means `glfwGetProcAddress` is a function that takes a string and returns **a pointer** to function with no parameters and no return value.

---

`GLADloadproc` is a type alias defined as follows:

```
typedef void* (* GLADloadproc)(const char *name);
```

Essentially, this means that this is the type of a function that takes a string and returns **a void pointer** (this is a type of pointer that can be safely converted to from every other type of pointer).

---

in the expression

```
gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)
```

Inside, there is the expression

```
(GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress
```

Where we have a **type** in parenthesis followed by an identifier. This is known as a **type cast**, it means we are taking some value of some type and converting it to some other type.

In this case, we take our `GLADloadproc` function that takes string and returns pointer to function and we 'disguise' it as a function that takes string and returns `void*`. This works because we can convert any pointer to `void*`, even in function pointer return types.

This is all to end up passing it to `gladLoadGLLoader`, which expects a value of type `GLADloadproc`.

---

TL;DR

`gladLoadGLLoader` takes a `GLADloadproc` but we want to give it a `GLFWglproc (*)(const char *)`. To be able to do this, we force the type system to take it anyways by using a **type cast**.

Comment: Great answer. You look young, how are you so smart :P

Comment: And the reason you pass this function pointer to the windowing system is so that the windowing system can use this "OpenGL extension loader mechanism" for loading functions...